# Where to handle logic in MVVM view models?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controller, logic, viewmodel

After some initial reading on WPF and MVVM i'm currently working on a small debug application for a digital IO controller. In this application i'v got a tree of view models, which looks like this:

IOControllerViewModel > ConfigurationViewModels > PortViewModels > ChannelViewModels

This corresponds to the business objects, where the IOController contains a set of Configurations, which then contains a list Ports, which then contains a list of Channels, which finally represent the input/output channels of the IO controller.

But now my question is where to handle the "logic"?

For example i want to toggle the state of a output channel. The IOControllerViewModel is currently the only instance, which has a reference to the business object, that contains the needed ToggleChannel() method. Now i see three options:

1. Put the login inside the ChannelViewModel. Thus pass the
   necessary business object from my root all way down to the leafs.
2. Put the logic inside the IOControllerViewModel. Thus an event or
   something similar must be fired by the ChannelViewModel and then
   handled by the IOControllerViewModel.
3. Introduce a controller, which is responsible for any logic and
   publish the controller to all view models.
4. Any other option? Best practice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What ToggleChannel() methid does? Which business objects it requires? in case of (1 option) which business objects you need to pass down?

Comment: The method reads the state of a channel, inverts the value and then writes the new state back. The only business objects required for this is the IOController, which is wrapped in the IOControllerViewModel. In fact, the other "business objects" in the hierarchy (Configuration, Port, Channels) don't include any logic at all. So there is not sense to wrap them into a ViewModel... seems that i have to review my (company's) whole architecture on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I put logic on the layer that uses it, and use a messaging system such as PRISM's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger` to communicate between ViewModels. (If you're interested, I wrote a brief post about this [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/))

In your case, it depends on what layer handles the login. For example, if a LoginViewModel successfully authenticates a user, it would broadcast something like a `UserAuthenticated` message, containing relevant parameters. Interested ViewModels could then subscribe to `UserAuthenticated` messages, and handle them accordingly.

Keep in mind that with MVVM, your ViewModels are you application. The app should run just fine without any Views at all (such as from a Test script)

Comment: Thanks Rachel! A lightweight event system seems to be just the thing i needed (beside some general architecture review ;))

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you're using a hierarchical structure which could live with just one ViewModel, the IOControllerViewModel. All those Configurations, Ports and Channels could be observable properties or collections of its corresponding item.

You would then just use an IOControllerView which contains an ItemsControl which accesses all configurations. In the DataTemplate of each configuration item you would have an ItemsControl which uses the ports as ItemsSource and so on.

It's not good to have more ViewModels than needed, especially if there's no need for a View because you could use a DataTemplate instead.

I hope I got you right.

Comment: Yeha, i also realized that i may have too much ViewModel's (comment above). This whole "design" needs a little review, and i some more MVVM skills :)